# RDS Postgres out of shared memory

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

i've the rds server from aws which contains two databases staging and development and the sessions is not that high however i receive an error of

> ErrorResponse: out of shared memory

the projects are node js applications used sequelize orm
is there's a solution that i can do
[image: aws pic for the database server]

Comment: Either increase the size of your DB, or optimize your application's use of the DB (this may not be possible to the extent you need).

Answer (score 0):

How did you set the shared_buffers option?

and.. your db instance it's really low type.

https://postgresqlco.nf/doc/en/param/shared_buffers/

> If you have a dedicated database server with 1GB or more of RAM, a reasonable starting value for shared_buffers is 25% of the memory in your system